# How to fix position of Arabic fatah over seen?

Tags: color, fontspec, polyglossia, arabxetex

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[voc]{arabxetex}

\setmainfont{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}

\newcommand{\clrfatha}[3][0pt]{%
\arabicfont%
\hskip#2\raisebox{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{\char"064E}}\hskip-#2%
\textcolor{purple}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}
{\fontsize{1.4cm}{2cm} \clrfatha[-8pt]{6pt}{س}} 
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

I need :
[image]

Comment: `\clrfatha[-8pt]{15pt}{س}` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you very much.